# Invalid MEX-file: Gateway function is missing

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to check whether the mex files I created from Xilinx bitaccurate model work correctly or not, so when I try to run them in matlab online, it shows:

```
>>run_cordic_mex
Invalid MEX-file '/MATLAB Drive/New Folder/cordic_v6_0_bitacc_mex.mexa64': Gateway function is missing
Error in run_cordic_mex (line 5) x_out = cordic_v6_0_bitacc_mex(x_in, [cordic_val_ph(1), cordic_val_ph(1)] , 18, 18, 0, 2, 0);
```

Please tell me how to fix this issue.
The link to the files are attached here:
[mex_files](https://easyupload.io/m/2pfjh6) [mex_files2](https://easyupload.io/m/ag1gsd)

Comment: Posts must be self-contained, code in an external link is not useful for the purposes of Stack Overflow. Please read [mre], and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: You are missing the required `void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, 
  const mxArray *prhs[])` function in the code that is generated in the mex, I think But impossible to know withut a [mcve] that is not attached to some shady donwload link.

Comment: thanks i'll include the mex function accordingly.